# Ember.js 2. Lazy fetch in background after rendering the page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, lazy-loading, ember-cli

I have a simple page "**authors**" that shows a list of authors.

Each author of course has **many books**, but in that page (*and in the API*) I don't show(*/include*) any book data.

In the authors route I have the default model():

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('author');
}
```

and everything is OK.

Now I need *something* that **fetch lazy** (**in background**) some data from others APIs (the books ones).

But I don't want this call blocking my authors page render. So, I have the default and speedy `beforeModel()`, `model()` and `afterModel()` without any fetch (except for authors data).

**ONLY after page** is rendered I need something (*maybe a service?*) that calls "`api/books?author:1,2,3,4,5...`"

In this way I already have the books in my "store" when someone click on an athor (no waiting loader in that book page).

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

## 1. If you want to lazily load and store relationship data without blocking UI:

If you do not want to display lazily loaded relationship data (in special `hasMany`-relationships), I would recommend doing so in the `afterModel`-hook:

*route.js*:

```
  // ...

  afterModel(authors) {
    let lastPromise = new Promise(function(resolve) { resolve(); });
    authors.forEach(author => {
      lastPromise = lastPromise.then(() => {
        return author.get('books');
      });
    });
  },

  // ...
```

## 2. If you want to lazily load, store and display relationship data without blocking UI:

There are several ways to do this. One way I prefer when lazy loading data is the following:

First I create a component which encapsulates the display and loading of my data. In your example I would call my component `book-shelf`.

After being inserted into the DOM my component wants to display its books. See the following code.

*component.js*:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {
  get,
  computed,
  ArrayProxy,
  PromiseProxyMixin,
  inject: { service }
} = Ember;

const ArrayPromiseProxy = ArrayProxy.extend(PromiseProxyMixin);

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  // API:
  author: null,

  // Internal:
  store: service(),
  books: computed(
    'author.id',
    function() {
      if(!get(this, 'author.id')) {
        return [];
      }
      return ArrayPromiseProxy.create({
        promise: get(this, 'store').query('book', { authorId: get(this, 'author.id') })
      });
    }
  ),
});
```

And in your *template.hbs*:

```
<div class="book-shelf">
  {{#if books.isFulfilled}}
    Books of {{author.name}}:
    <ul>
      {{#each books as |book|}}
        <li>{{book.name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{else}}
    Loading... please wait...
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

This approach combines an array proxy with a promise proxy in order to act like an array but also provide information whether the data is loaded.

You can use this component as every component in ember.js:

```
{{book-shelf author=mySpecialAuthor}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Timm, but I need this not in DOM, not in a component. In the authors page I need (ONLY AFTER RENDERING of the authors page) to fetch in background the books data. In this way the book data of every author is ready for the click on any author (and book page rendering...).

Comment: so perhaps the new added "first" solution will work for you?